# Is singular cohomology with rational coefficients vector space over the field $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to understand singular cohomology. The following is correct? singular cohomology with rational coefficients vector space over the field $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes. Cohomology with coefficients in a ring $R$ is always a $R$-module. In particular it is a vector space over $R$, if $R$ is a field.